# How to store fresh peaches?

Tags: storage-method, fresh, peaches

I bought fresh, ripe peaches, and I don't eat them super fast. I want them to last fresh for as long as possible. How should I store them?

Helpful details would address:

1. Under what parameters would I use plastic? Should I seal it? Can the peaches touch the plastic?
2. If I refrigerate, what drawer should they go in?
3. What other foods should or should they not be near?
4. Should I store them submerged, moist, dry, or with absorbent material?

Answer (score 1):

For ripe peaches the main thing is avoid handling them.  They bruise very easily.  I leave them in the box and just slide the box in a shelf in the fridge.  You are only going to get a few days out of them.

Never in a drawer as too much handling.  Don't stack.  Dry.  I would never wrap or seal to keep mold down but that part is more opinion than hard evidence.